# Can not import action bar sherlock in Android IDE with gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

I've just started using Android IDE (Intellij Idea) and I've imported actionbarsherlock and navigation drawer into the libraries directory but idea shows me this error:

```
  Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project 
':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock'.
Plugin with id 'android-library' not found.
```

Here is the build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
    dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    }
    android {
      compileSdkVersion 14
      buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

      sourceSets {
       main {
         manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
         java.srcDirs = ['src']
         res.srcDirs = ['res']
       }
     }
  }
```

and settings.gradle

```
 include ':IBus',
':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock',
':libraries:SherlockNavigationDrawer:SherlockNavigationDrawer'
```

Comment: Are you building ABS from local sources?

Comment: yes, i've added source projects into libraries folder

Comment: Just in case - are you modifying them? The purpose of having ABS in sources but not as aar?

Comment: i'm new to android studio, i thought that it would be the same logic as in eclise, where you can import library project into workspace and build path to them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you're not working under ABS and having this dependency in sources doesn't have sense.

Remove ABS from **settings.gradle** and update **build.gradle** dependencies to next:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
  compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

I'm not sure if other dependencies are providing jar or aar in maven central. So I don't know how to fix other dependencies but I'm sure that it is possible to do with multimodule project. Which means you should have general **settings.gradle** and **build.gradle** for every library